# Color sampler, like firebug, but for image text

Tags: html, css, firebug

I use firebug to check colors on webpages, but sometimes the color is from an image. Is there a firefox plugin like firebug that can act as a color sampler this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/firefox/) should do everything you need.

> Advanced Eyedropper, Color Picker, Palette Viewer and other colorful goodies for your Firefox

Comment: wow exactly what I needed. Thank you Pekka. SO does not allow choosing the right answer until 10 mins later, so will mark it as answered then.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you specified a Firefox addin but this is a free tool that will allow you to get the colour from any window on the system so might be more versatile http://www.bayden.com/mezer/ (If you are on Windows)